# Assembler - skipping instructions

Tags: assembly, gdb, mips, skip

I am currently writing some stuff in MIPS-Assembler and I have some trouble:
I wrote this function:

```
PRINT_FLOAT:

        addi $sp, $sp, -4       #stackpointer um ein wort weiterrücken
        sw $ra, 0($sp)          #rücksprungadresse auf stack speichern
        la $a0, strFloat
        add $a1, $s0, $zero
        jal printf
        lw $ra, 0($sp)          #rücksprungadresse aus stack holen
        addi $sp, $sp, 4        #stackpointer um ein wort zurückrücken
        jr $ra
```

if I run this program the instruction add $a1, $s0, $zero is skipped and I don't know why...

Another funny thing, if I debug this program with GDB:

```
  main:

        addi $t0, $zero, 3
        addi $t0, $zero, 3
        addi $t0, $zero, 3
        jal READ_FLOAT

        jal PRINT_FLOAT
```

and set a breakpoint at main, the breakpoint is set at the third "addi $t0, $zero, 3"
What happens here?

Comment: Are you assembling with optimization? That would make sense with the three `addi` statements, since they all do the same thing making two of them superfluous.

Comment: is your assembler putting add in the branch delay slot?  what does your disassembly show for this code?  used to you had to explicityly do it, the last time I used gnu assembler it simply swapped the instruction in front with the branch, had to explicitly tell it not to.  or tell it that the architecture doesnt have the branch delay slot.

Answer (score 2):

`gdb` is a high level source debugger, so it's a little harder to deal with asm on an instruction by instruction basis.

For example, to step through C code, normally the "s" [step] command is used. But, `gdb` will "step across" any asm sequence that it considers to be part of a single C statement.

To step individual asm instructions, you want the "si" [step instruction] command. See `help si`

Likewise, when setting breakpoints, you want to use a modified form of the command. `break * whatever` to set a breakpoint at *address* `whatever`. See `help break`

To be able to get the correct addresses, you may need to disassemble a bit, so see `help disassemble` and `help x`. To disassemble a single instruction, `x/i ...` also works.

As, dwelch pointed out, your assembler may "get cute" and reorder things. By having `gdb` do the disassembly, you'll be able to see whether this has happened or not. And, if branch delay slots *are* enabled/active on the actual processor, you'll need to account for them. For example, when running with a simulator such as `spim` or `mars`, use of branch delay slots is configurable [and default off], but with a real processor, there may be no choice.

> if I run this program the instruction add $a1, $s0, $zero is skipped and I don't know why...

That may be why you *think* the `add $a1,$s0,$zero` instruction is being skipped. `gdb` [with "step"] will treat the following as a single block:

```
    la      $a0,strFloat
    add     $a1,$s0,$zero
    jal     printf
```

> the breakpoint is set at the third `addi $t0, $zero, 3`

Once again, for the same reason as above. Use the alternate form of the breakpoint command.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a breakpoint at function and there is no debug information available, gdb tries to set a breakpoint after a [function prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue).

Gdb analyzes machine instructions to detect a prologue. "addi $sp, $sp, -4" looks like it might be recognized as prologue (but I'm no MIPS expert so I may be wrong).

Enable debug information when assembling/linking and gdb should have more information about frames available.

You can also disassemble your main (disas main) and set a breakpoint to address of first instruction (like this: break *0xabcdef) instead of "break main".

Comment: Based on the MIPS disassemby I've reviewed "addi $sp, $sp, -4" increases the stack size by 4 bytes. There is usually a complementary line at the end of a function "addi $sp,$sp,4" to reduce the stack by the same amount.